# Schedule completed event is not supported by stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe schedules to handle the downgrade of the subscriptions. I need to test it, however, the events `subscription_schedule.completed` is not supported by stripe CLI(Even I upgraded to latest verison).

Theres no way on stripe dashboard to compelte the schedule before time.I need to do handle stuff on my backend after this event is triggered, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscription_schedule.completed` events are sent when a Subscription Schedule transitions to having a status of `completed`. This happens when the Schedule has `end_behavior: cancel` and was allowed to end naturally by completing its last phase (not through an API call to cancel it).

You can trigger `subscription_schedule.completed` events yourself by updating or creating a new Subscription Schedule that ends a few seconds in the future and has `end_behavior: cancel`. Here's an example of how you would do this using curl (replacing FUTURE_TIMESTAMP with one that is a few seconds in the future, and using your own keys and object IDs):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_schedules \
  -u sk_test_XXX: \
  -d customer=cus_XXX \
  -d start_date=now \
  -d end_behavior=cancel \
  -d "phases[0][items][0][price]"=price_XXX \
  -d "phases[0][items][0][quantity]"=1 \
  -d "phases[0][end_date]"={{FUTURE_TIMESTAMP}}
```